# <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">"User Already Exists !"</string>

Tags: android

"User Already Exists !" how to get inner body value like "User Already Exists !"  I am using DOM Parser

please post any example

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: i want to fetch string value User Already Exists ! in action tag

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: <string xmlns=“http://tempuri.org/”>“User Already Exists !”</string>

Comment: this is a .net web service response data

Answer (score 0):

```
 private EditText email, name, mobile, password;
TextView tv;
private Button submit;
```

// private String Email, Name, Mobile, Password;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);

        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s1 = email.getText().toString().trim();

                String s2 = name.getText().toString().trim();
                String s3 = mobile.getText().toString().trim();

                String s4 = password.getText().toString().trim();
                if (s1.length() > 0 && s2.length() > 0) {
                    new ExecuteTask().execute(s1, s2, s3, s4);
                    email.setText(s1);

                    name.setText(s2);
                    mobile.setText(s3);


                    password.setText(s4);

                } else {

                }

            }
        });
    }



public String PostData(String[] valuse) {
    String responseText = "";
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(
                "https://www.businessbook4u.com/bbm4u.asmx/XUsrSignup?Email="+valuse[0]+"&Name="+valuse[1]+"&Mobile="+valuse[2]+"&Password="+valuse[3]);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return responseText;
}
class ExecuteTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String res = PostData(params);
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
        t.setText(s);


       }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am also using with Ksoap2 but Java.net.SocketTimeoutexception always show

Comment: ## this type problum to fatch data not json ##

  `  
    // data match the server
   <soap12:Body>
    <XUsrSignup xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Email>string</Email>
      <Name>string</Name>
      <Mobile>string</Mobile>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </XUsrSignup>
  </soap12:Body>

// data get from server

 <soap12:Body>
    <XUsrSignupResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <XUsrSignupResult>string</XUsrSignupResult>
    </XUsrSignupResponse>
  </soap12:Body>`